# I am unable to print the letter 'A' using star pattern in PHP

Tags: php

I am trying to print the letter 'A' using star pattern but somewhere I am getting wrong. The code is as follow-

```
<?php
 for ($row=0; $row<=7; $row++)
{
  for ($column=0; $column<=7; $column++)
    {
        if ((($column == 1 or $column == 5) and $row != 0) or (($row == 0 or $row == 3) and ($column > 1 and $column < 5)))
            echo "*";    
        else  
            echo " ";     
    }        
  echo "<br>";
}

?>
```

The letter A does not appear in proper format.

Comment: Are you viewing it in a browser? It is correct to me. Replace the space with `&nbsp;` if viewing in a browser. Multiple single spaces are joined in browsers. Your current code, https://eval.in/841189.

Comment: ... or output it in a `pre` element. There is nothing wrong with the code per se; but your knowledge of HTML basics such as how whitespace is handled seems to need improving ...

Comment: the other option is to echo your letter inside a `<pre>` tag to keep all the spaces and replace `<br>` with `\n`

Comment: Thank you all! your comments helped me a lot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just add in your else block `echo "&nbsp;&nbsp;";`

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't use spaces. CHoose another character or use `&nbsp;`, which is an unbreakable space.

Web browsers remove consecutive spaces so that there is only one space between two non-spaces characters. That's why your display looks broken.

Unbreakable spaces will be printed no matter what.